# How to create a bank account with user input?

Tags: java

I have following classes in the project:

- Account
- Customer
- Name: fName and lName (both are String fields)
- Date: year, month, day (all are int fields)
- Bank: contains collection of accounts
- InputReader: reads the input from the keyboard

An Account object requires a Customer object and an opening balance. 
A Customer object requires a Name object and a Date object. 
A Name object requires Strings for first and last names 
I need to ask the user for the details to create the Name and Date objects, and also the opening balance.

I have to create a new Account by getting the relevant information from the user, i.e. it asks the user to type in the customer's name, date of birth etc. It reads in the user responses, creates the account and adds it to the bank.

I keep getting an error message saying "java.lang.NullPointerException" when I run the public void createNewAccount() method. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my source code for the Bank class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank
{
    public static final double INTEREST_RATE = 0.012;//1.2%
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
    private InputReader reader;
    private Name fullName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Bank
     */
    public Bank()
    {
        // initialise instance variables

    }

    /*
     * Adds an existing Account to the bank
     * @param account
     */
    public void addAccount(Account account)
    {
        accounts.add(account);
    }

       public void createNewAccount() { 

        System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = reader.readString();

        System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + ". " + "What is your last name?");
        String lastName = reader.readString();
        System.out.println("Your last name is " + lastName);


        System.out.println("Please enter your year of birth: ");
        int thisYear = reader.readInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter your month of birth: ");
        int thisMonth = reader.readInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth: ");
        int thisDay = reader.readInt();

        Name theName = new Name(firstName, lastName);
        Date theDateOfBirth = new Date(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay);

    }


}
```

Comment: `reader` is used before initializing. Complete the initialization portion of your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change reader with Scanner. Something like that.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
    String firstName = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + ". " + "What is your last name?");
    String lastName = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Your last name is " + lastName);


    System.out.println("Please enter your year of birth: ");
    int thisYear = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your month of birth: ");
    int thisMonth = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth: ");
    int thisDay = scan.nextInt();

  //Then do what you are supposed to do......
```

Comment: thanks for the info! I tried another method which works but yours also makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize reader before you can attempt to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

The scanner object has a lot of functions you can use;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your InputReader reader is declared, but not initialised, hence NullPointerExceptin. Change it to more commonly used:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then you can use it's methods for user input:

```
scanner.nextLine() for strings

scanner.nextInt() for ints

scanner.nextDouble() for doubles
```

etc.

Check the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your instance variables:

```
public class Bank
{
    public static final double INTEREST_RATE = 0.012;

    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
    private InputReader reader;
    private Name fullName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public Bank()
    {
        // initialise instance variables <- where it says to
        accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
        reader = new InputReader();
        ...
    }
```

InputReader must be part of the assignment package so I don't know what its constructor properly is.